# Why does command append(i) adds last element from previous call?

Tags: python, python-2.7, append

I am doing Shaw's exercise 32, from his book "Learn Python the Hard Way". First of all, this is the code from the exercise:

```
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'apricots']
change = [1, 'pennies', 2, 'dimes', 3, 'quarters']

# this first kind of for-loop goes through a list
for number in the_count:
    print "This is count %d" % number

# same as above
for fruit in fruits:
    print "A fruit of type: %s" % fruit

# also we can go through mixed lists too 
# notice we have %r since we don't know what's in it.
for i in change:
    print "I got %r" % i

# we can also build lists, first start with an empty one
elements = range(0, 6)

# then use the range function to do 0 to 5 counts
#for i in range(0, 6):
print "Adding %r to the list." % elements
# append is a function that lists understand
#elements.append(i)

# now we can print them out too
for i in elements:
    print "Element was: %r" % i
```

In *Study Drills* I stumbled upon simple task, which is:

> Could you have avoided that for- loop entirely on line 22 and just assigned range(0,6) directly to elements?

I changed it from this:

```
elements = []

for i in range(0, 6):
    print "Adding %r to the list." % elements
elements.append(i)
```

To this:

```
elements = range(0,6)

print "Adding %r to the list." % elements
elements.append(i)
```

Still, the output, before commenting out `elements.append(i)` was:

```
This is count 1
This is count 2
This is count 3
This is count 4
This is count 5
A fruit of type: apples
A fruit of type: oranges
A fruit of type: pears
A fruit of type: apricots
I got 1
I got 'pennies'
I got 2
I got 'dimes'
I got 3
I got 'quarters'
Adding [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to the list.
Element was: 0
Element was: 1
Element was: 2
Element was: 3
Element was: 4
Element was: 5
Element was: 'quarters'
```

Why is the last line printed? Or, more precisely, why `append` adds `quarters`? What is the mechanism behind it?

P.S. I would like to know *why it will get / is this getting* downvoted, since I want to improve next time I dare to ask question here at SO.

Comment: Without the loop you've never changed `i` from the previous value it held. This is one reason using the same loop variable in every loop isn't a good idea. You're not actually using `elements`, just printing it out. Also, FYI: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: Since you're just starting out you really ought to be learning Python 3. Python 2 reaches its official End of Life in 2020. And learning Python 2 as a precursor to Python 3 is not really helpful. It's like learning Shakespeare's English as a precursor to learning modern English. ;)

Comment: Thank you both! I have found many complaints about his approach to Python 3 and 2 since I started doing exercises.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `for i in change:`, `i` is a local variable. Which means it is accessable in the whole local scope instead of only `for` block.

So after `for` block, `i` equals to the last value in loop.

Answer (score -1):

In Python 2, the variable initiated in a for statement can slip through and can be used even outside the for loop. The scope of the variable initiated in the for syntax is local scope. Meaning, if the for loop resides in a function, the variable will have scope of the function. If the for loop is in a module, the variable will have scope of the module itself.

When there is a `elements.append(i)`, this appends the value of `i` to the `elements` list. This is not necessary in your case, as we are using the `range` function.

Do note that, this is *still* the case with Python 3. In Python 3, the variable initiated in the `for` statement *is also* accessible outside.

EDIT: Updated the last paragraph, where I claimed that Python 3 did not have the "feature" to factual one. The only way to avoid the "feature" is either through list comprehensions or through closures.

Comment: That absolutely still happens with regular `for` loops in Python 3. It's list comprehensions, which the OP isn't using, where you see a difference.